# How can I sort a string based on the ASCII value of the characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, ascii

I am trying to create a program that can get a string and return the string with the characters sorted by their ASCII Values (Ex: "Hello, World!" should return "!,HWdellloor").

I've tried this and it worked :

```
text = "Hello, World!"
cop = []
for i in range(len(text)):
    cop.append(ord(text[i]))
cop.sort()
ascii_text = " ".join([str(chr(item)).strip() for item in cop])
print(ascii_text)
```

But I was curious to see if something like this is possible with string manipulation functions alone.

Comment: Why? Why not just order the characters? Besides, in Python 3 strings are Unicode not ASCII.

Comment: `''.join(sorted(text))`. A string is a sequence. Calling `ord()` is unnecessary (it does not change the sort order to convert to integer).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos indeed, but i am looking to sort based on ascii value

Comment: @DietrichEpp thanks, now i feel stupid but at least it worked xd

Comment: Sidenote: to create `cop` much more easily: `cop = [ord(c) for c in text]`. Also, `str(chr())` is redundant.

Comment: @Luca Is ASCII actually relevant? The code you wrote uses the Unicode codepoint (from `ord()`). Maybe you want to encode the characters first?

Answer (score 0):

Ascii is a subset of Unicode. The first 127 codepoints of Unicode are identical to the first 127 codepoints of ascii (though when ascii was invented in 1963 they didn't use the word *codepoint*). So if your data is all ascii and you just call the built-in `sort()` method or the `sorted()` function, you will get it in ascii order.

Like this:

```
>>> text = "Hello, World!"
>>> ''.join(sorted(text))
' !,HWdellloor'
```

The result is sorted by the Unicode codepoint of the character, but since that is the same as the ascii codepoint, there is no difference.

As you can see, the first character in the sorted result is a space, ascii 32, which is the printable character with the lowest codepoint, 32 (yes, you can argue about whether it is printable) followed by digits (codepoints 48-57), then the uppercase letters (65-90), then the lowercase letters (97-122), with punctuation and symbols scattered in the gaps between, and control codes like carriage return and linefeed in the range 0-31 and 127.

You can confirm this by sorting `string.ascii_letters`:

```
>>> import string
>>> ''.join(sorted(string.ascii_letters))
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

and then checking the sequence against [one of the many](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) ascii tables available.

If you are wondering about the placement of the various blocks of characters, uppercase and lowercase were arranged in such a way that there was a one-bit difference between an uppercase character (example `A`: 0x41) and the corresponding lowercase character (`a`: 0x61), which simplified case-insensitive matching; and there were similar arguments for placement of the other blocks. For some of the control codes there were strong legacy imperatives, from punched paper tape patterns.